# "Force stop" Option still avaliable after app was destroyed

Tags: android, ondestroy

I noticed that after I quit an app using the back button, when I go to the "Manage apps" menu I still have an option "Force Stop". Shouldn't the app be already dead at this point? (I made sure that OnDestroy indeed runs).
Why would I have an option to force stop an app that's officially dead?

Thanks,

Geva Tal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `BACK` button finishes an `Activity`, i.e., the current UI part of an 'app'.

A common mistake is to assume that an `Activity` is the entire 'app' which is not necessarily the case. As CommonsWare points out, it is not necessary for the OS to immediately clean up all of the parts related to the process in which an `Activity` runs - in fact it can be counter-intuitive if a user briefly leaves an `Activity` but then re-visits it shortly after.

Android is actually very efficient at managing resources and releasing them (if needed for other 'apps'). What gets retained / maintained after a particular `Activity` finishes isn't worth worrying about...or at least it *shouldn't* be if the developer has correctly cleaned up things in their code.

Part of the culture of 'App Killer' apps is related to people assuming that apps don't clean up properly when an `Activity` finishes. If written correctly, they do and Android will do the rest if/when necessary.

Answer (score 3):

> I noticed that after I quit an app using the back button, when I go to the "Manage apps" menu I still have an option "Force Stop". Shouldn't the app be already dead at this point?

No.

> Why would I have an option to force stop an app that's officially dead?

Because the process is not "dead". Android will keep your process around for a bit, in case the user happens to pop back into your app in the not-too-distant future. Android will terminate your process if and when it needs the RAM to support other apps.

The behavior you are seeing is perfectly normal.